# Trying to Reduce HTTP Requests With CSS Sprites But Now Images Don't Appear Properly

Tags: html, css, httprequest, css-sprites

To try and reduce the number of HTTP requests I have combined groups of related images into sprites.

I understand the methodology behind it but I can't seem to get it to work correctly for the ones I am working one and would love some help.

Here is the new markup and css (previous markup just had individual img tags wrapped in the anchor tag):

```
<div id="footer-flags">
    <ul>
        <li class="countryName">Region: </li>
        <li class="active countryFlag" id="uk"><a title="United Kingdom" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li> 
        <li class="countryFlag" id="us"><a title="United States" target="_blank" href="http://www.us-site.us"></a></li> 
        ... 5 more
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS is as seen below:

```
#footer-flags {
    float:right;    
}
#footer-flags ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:-3px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
}
#footer-flags ul li {
    background-image: url(/img/flags/flags-sprite.jpg);
    height: 11px;
    width: 14px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:3px;
}
#footer-flags #de {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#footer-flags #fr {
    background-position: 0px -11px;
}
#footer-flags #hr {
    background-position: 0px -22px;
}
#footer-flags #ie {
    background-position: 0px -33px;
}
#footer-flags #nl {
    background-position: 0px -44px;
}
#footer-flags #uk {
    background-position: 0px -55px;
}
#footer-flags #us {
    background-position: 0px -66px;
}

#footer-flags ul li.active {
    background:url("/img/flags/flag-highlight.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    margin-right:-5px;
    padding:3px 5px 5px;
}
```

The sprite image is 14px x 77px (so the flags are positioned on top of each other).

Here is a fiddle if anyone prefers it: http://jsfiddle.net/WNXNz/4/

The error itself is just that the flag images are strewn all over the place and the links don't seem to be there aswell, i.e. the images aren't clickable.

From what I can see I think I have implemented it correctly but it's likely my CSS is a nightmare because I have only had to use a sprite before and it was just for one image.

Comment: The a-tags have no content, and as inline-elements they collapse to 0px height. Try setting them to `display: block` or something. Or try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WNXNz/6/

Comment: thank you, that's perfect! The only problem I now have is when you are one a specific site, the flag has a background image attached to it - as you can see in the css and the fiddle. Now, due to the sprites, the active flag doesn't show and neither does the 'highlight' image. Any ideas how to do this? Applying a background image to a sprite doesn't sound right to me :{ . I may have to open another question on SO for this I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Sprites shouldn't be used for HTML img. You now have **empty links**: this is bad for accessibility and SEO.

Accessibility: you can check the relevant WCAG 2.0 Technique [H30: Providing link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30)
People that disable images, CSS, use a screen reader or use the High Contrast mode in Windows won't be able to know there's a link there or won't know what it can possibly do.

SEO: I'm not a SEO specialist, all I can tell is that searchbots will have to guess from the destination what is the purpose of your link, that's not by far the best way to rank well in search engines.

That said, CSS sprites are great for background images :)

Comment: thanks for your input, I agree with you, I'm not sure sprites are best for this because we are losing the `alt` attribute. The powers that be want the page to load faster so sprites is one of the measures being taken.

Comment: It's CSS sprites, not image sprites so yes no alt should suffer from CSS sprites ;) If you want to influence "the powers that be" (you're one, too, the technical one), talk to them about SEO. They love to hear from poor ranking in Google. And maybe of frustrated users.